# What params on string block (<<-BLOCK, param1, param2) means?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm reading some source code at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise and found that line of code:

```
class_eval <<-URL_HELPERS, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
```

What the params `__FILE__` and `__LINE__ + 1` does in block declaration (what changes in relation of a string block without these params)?

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/url_helpers.rb#L47

Thank

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those params belong to the [class_eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-class_eval) method, not to the [here document](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#here_doc). It's common practice to ensure that error, which can raise the evaled code, will be shown with a reference to the current file and with correct line number.

Comment: I mean the influence of params on string block declaration, not the class_eval method

Comment: Nice, I could not imagine that. Thank you very much =)

Comment: @daniloisr You're welcome :) Don't forget to [accept answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 2):

By way of an alternative example showing how HEREDOCs work, the other day in IRB I wrote:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.XML(<<ENDXML,&:noblanks)
  ...gobs and gobs of pasted xml...
ENDXML
```

Even crazier is this legal syntax for passing multiple HEREDOC strings at once:

```
p( <<END1, <<-END2, <<END3 )
  This indented text is part of
  the first parameter, END1
END1
And this text is part of param2
  whose ending sigil may be indented
  END2
and finally this text
is part of
the third parameter
END3
#=> "  This indented text is part of\n  the first parameter, END1\n"
#=> "And this text is part of param2\n  whose ending sigil may be indented\n"
#=> "and finally this text\nis part of\nthe third parameter\n"
```